# Do .NET buttons fire events only if there's at least one subscriber?

Tags: c#, .net, button

I'm designing a client-side test script generation application. The application finds every automation element in the provider and registers a listener on to each automation element in the provider. Whenever the user interacts with the provider's UI, the automation elements fire events which are recorded in my application. 
Right now, the buttons on the main form fire events, but the buttons in subforms don't fire events. I realized that subform buttons don't have subscribers in the provider's code. So my question is, do .NET buttons only fire events if there's at least one subscriber?

Comment: Events can't be fired unless there's a subscriber (the EventHandler would be null, and so can't be invoked).  Don't your test script's listeners count as subscribers?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but when your app iterates the provider for automation elements, does it take into account children of said provider or children of the element ?

Comment: I agree with where Tim S. is going; I would have thought that adding a listener would be enough to give the object's event at least 1 subscriber.

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: This is on the verge of being a stupid question. Perhaps you need a coffee? :)

Comment: Yes, when my code iterates through the windows tree it takes into account every single automation element and registers a listener, depending on the supported pattern. So if the element supports InvokePattern, I would do
`Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
InvokePattern.InvokedEvent,
buttonElement,
Treescope.Element,
invokeEventHandler);`

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit like asking "If a tree falls in a forest and there's no one to hear it, does it make a sound?" If you go there to find out, there *is* someone to hear it.

When a handler is attached to a .NET event, a collection object is created and a delegate added to it. When an event occurs, the framework checks for the existence of this collection. When present, its elements are enumerated and invoked, otherwise event dispatch terminates early.

"[D]o .NET buttons only fire events if there's at least one subscriber?"

If by "fire events" you mean "invoke delegates to call event handlers" then clearly this can only occur when there *are* delegates. Obviously if there aren't any then they can't be invoked. In the sense of "Does the framework *look* for delegates to call when there aren't any" then the event *does* fire in the absence of handlers.

Comment: Yes, but do .Net button elements look for delegates in separate, client applications?

Comment: In what way is the separate application a client? .net remoting is the only way I have imagine that you could bind an event handler to something in another AppDomain, and remoting hasn't been a recommended distributed application technology for a very long time.